# ASP.Net 5 configuration dependency injection and static controller constructors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net 5 offers an [options pattern](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects) to easily convert any POCO class into a settings class. Using this I can write my settings in json and then turn them into a typed object that I can inject into my controllers. So, for example, my `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` contains the line

```cs
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

and then this gets passed into my controllers' constructors using dependency injection

```cs
public ItemsController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings) { /* do stuff */ }
```

One of my controllers fires up a [DNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_neural_network) to do some of its work. To reduce the cost of starting the DNN I do that from the static class constructor. Static constructors are parameterless and so I cannot pass in the required settings object, but I could set a static `IOptions<AppSettings>` property on the `ItemsController` from my `ConfigureServices` method. How do I get at that? Where is the dependency injector and how do I persuade it to hand me an `IOptions<AppSettings>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking at the problem wrong. The problem is that you *have* a static class and are using DI, not how to inject your dependencies into a static class (which cannot be done without resorting to a [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) or another hack).

Most DI containers have a singleton lifestyle, which allows you to share the same instance of an object across your application. Using this approach, there is no need for a static class. Eliminate the static class by replacing it with an singleton instance, and you have an avenue where you can inject dependencies into your constructor.

Comment: Great, for this. A better way of thinking about it and a solution :-)

Comment: Some classes have a static component and instance components.  Example, I have a configurable value that I want to load once (static) and use in all instances.  Should I break the class into two and use DI lifetime control?

Comment: In general, you should strive to do all configuration in your composition root. This implicitly means that global configuration values should flow through the constructor of the services. You could either provide a separate object for the configuration (think XmlReaderSettings) or create an abstract factory or [fluent builder](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) so the class can either be populated with provided values or logical defaults. For settings that are rarely changed from their default, you may consider using a public property rather than a constructor parameter.